# JSOM Remote Access Office 365 Site

Tags: client-object-model, office-365

From a remote web app(plain ASP.NET), I am trying to read the data from an office365 SharePoint site using JSOM.  I am using the following code

```
                var siteUrl = "https://spdev101365.sharepoint.com/sites/DevedsloperSite"; //For the moment just hard coding this
                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
                var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(siteUrl);
                ctx.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);

                var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyCustomList');
                var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); //The Query object. This is used to query for data in the List
                query.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit></RowLimit>10</View>');

                var collListItem = oList.getItems(query);

                ctx.load(oList); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.
                ctx.load(collListItem);

                ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.successHandler), Function.createDelegate(this, this.errorHandler));
```

My First quest is, is this possible in the first place? and if so what am I missing here (I get an authentication failure message).

Comment: I don't think it is possible because of Same Origin Policy, not even through app policy, you need a proxy. But I just have to ask, how did you get access to `SP` in your JavaScript if you have a plain APT.NET site?

Comment: I got access by just adding the required javascript (sp.js and so on) as references.

Comment: Just referring them from the SharePoint site then? I thought at least some of the sp-scripts depended on the dynamic inline scripts on the page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can get the list items using REST.

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Test')/items
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" or "application/atom+xml"
```